# Only alert once? After full function is run

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, alert

Hi how do I make that the alert should happen only once?

```
$.ajax({
  url: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.appear/0.3.3/jquery.appear.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true,
  success: function() {
    $("#footer").appear();

    $("body").on("appear", "#footer", function() {
      alert('Footer');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: @RayonDabre How would you change my code snippet?

Comment: after which full function

Comment: @ArunPJohny when footer have been alerted.

Comment: So the alert should happen only once

Comment: check the console for errors -- why are you loading appear js like that?

Comment: @ArunPJohny correct maybe `.done()` can work?

Comment: @Tasos it's a jquery plugin

Comment: yeah i know that, but load it in the head of the document

Comment: @Tasos I can't do that, I'm using a tag management system

Comment: ahh ok, the demo below works anyway

Comment: @Tasos if I want to fetch more elements than the footer, how would I achieve that? what should I google for?

Comment: here ("#footer") you just add a comma for each element id eg ("#header, #container, #footer")

Comment: @Tasos you're the best

Comment: thank you for the complement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the handler to trigger only once then use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one) to register the event handler

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.appear/0.3.3/jquery.appear.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true,
  success: function() {}
}).done(function() {
  $("#footer").appear();

  $("body").one("appear", "#footer", function() {
    alert('Footer');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<footer id="footer">asdf</footer>
```